# How do I carry over identical texture mapping when exporting to DAE?

Tags: collada, meshlab

I am able to open a 3DS file in MeshLab and when I export to Collada DAE format the textures are visible but they are not being projected onto the mesh in the same way as the preview in MeshLab. For example, the front/back faces of a cube would have the proper texture (suppose it's a polka dot) but the top and bottom have a striped look. How can I apply a single texture and have it appear as intended on all faces, like the imported model before I convert it?

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot of your problem? Opening the output DAE file in meshlab again is wrong or is ok?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It got me thinking about my problem from a different angle and I answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a result of the end software being used to view the DAE file. It's not a problem with MeshLab.

For example, if loading the file into Away3D be sure to handle the texture materials using the TextureMaterial class instead of the simpler SinglePassMaterialBase such as what you might find in their example code. Here is what I use now, and it displays texture properly:

```
var material:TextureMaterial = cast(asset, TextureMaterial);
material.ambientColor = 0xffffff;
material.lightPicker = _lightPicker;
material.shadowMethod = new FilteredShadowMapMethod(_light);
material.lightPicker = _lightPicker;
material.gloss = 30;
material.specular = 1;
material.ambient = 1;
material.repeat = true;
```